# Непонятная ошибка при удалении элемента - react.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Выдает ошибку `Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`, ругается на этот кусок кода. Я только учусь, не судите строго. Не пойму почему эта ошибка, и почему не могу удалить созданный элемент. Данные храню в `localStorage`.

```
  handleDelete(){
      this.props.onDelete(this.props.id);
  }
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import './App.css';


const DEFAULT_COLOR = 'tomato';

class Note extends Component {
    handleDelete(){
      this.props.onDelete(this.props.id);
    }

render(){
    const {
      color,
      text,
      title,
      onDelete
    } = this.props;
    return(
        <div className="note-item" style={{backgroundColor: color}}>
            <button onClick={this.handleDelete}>x</button>
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <p>{text}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
}

class NoteEditor extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      text: ''
    };
    this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
    this.handleTitleChange = this.handleTitleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleNoteAdd = this.handleNoteAdd.bind(this);
}
handleTextChange(e){
  this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
  });
}
handleTitleChange(e){
    this.setState({
        title: e.target.value
    });
}
handleNoteAdd(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  const newNote = {
    text: this.state.text,
    title: this.state.title,
    id: Date.now(),
    color: DEFAULT_COLOR
  };
  this.props.onNoteAdd(newNote);
  this.resetState();
}
resetState(){
    this.setState({
        text: '',
        title: ''
    })
}
render(){
  return(
      <div>
        <form action="" className="editor-form" onSubmit={this.handleNoteAdd}>
          <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter Your Title"
              value={this.state.title}
              onChange={this.handleTitleChange}
          />
          <textarea
              rows={5}
              placeholder="Enter Your Notes"
              value={this.state.text}
              onChange={this.handleTextChange}
          />
          <button
              disabled={!this.state.text && !this.state.title}
          >
            Add
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
  )
}
}

class NotesGrid extends Component {
render(){
  const {
    notes,
    onNoteDelete
  } = this.props;
  return(
      <div className="notes-grid-wrap">
          {
            notes.map(note =>
              <Note
                  key={note.id}
                  color={note.color}
                  id={note.id}
                  text={note.text}
                  title={note.title}
                  onDelete={onNoteDelete}
              />
            )
          }
      </div>
  )
}
}

class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
this.state = {
    notes : []
};
this.handleNoteAdd = this.handleNoteAdd.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount(){
const savedNotes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('notes'));

if (savedNotes) {
  this.setState({notes: savedNotes})
}
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){
if(prevProps.notes !== prevState.notes){
    this.saveToLocalStorage();
}
}

handleNoteAdd(newNote){
this.setState({
    notes: [newNote, ...this.state.notes]
})
}

handleNoteDelete(noteId){
  console.log(this.state.notes);
  this.setState({
      notes: this.state.notes.filter(note => note.id !== noteId)
  });
}

saveToLocalStorage(){
const notes = JSON.stringify(this.state.notes);
localStorage.setItem('notes', notes);
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>NotesApp</h1>
    <NoteEditor onNoteAdd={this.handleNoteAdd} />
    <NotesGrid notes={this.state.notes} onNoteDelete={this.handleNoteDelete}/>
  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Разобрался, нужно чуть ли не каждую функцию `.bind` - ить, кто может доступно пояснить почему так?

Comment: Не могу удалить элемент, почему?

Comment: `.bind`-ить нужно, потому как в функции неизвестно что такое `this`(или что вы под ним подразумеваете). Этого можно не делать, если использовать стрелочные функции. Тогда в контексте класса будет понятно, что такое `this`

Comment: @Klimenkomud Спасибо за информацию. Не можете подсказать по коду, почему не получается удалить элемент?

Comment: Попробуйте вот так: `let notes= this.state.notes.filter(note => note.id !== noteId); this.setState({notes: notes});` И при входе в функцию сделайте `console.log(noteId);` Может вы как-то неправильно передаете `id` вашего `note`.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, все было гораздо проще, нужно было за `bind`-ить функцию. Переписал на стрелочную, и все работает как надо